# Chrome: Selecting a link by doing search on its text

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, web

I'm trying to use my computer using the keyboard exclusively, without touching the mouse. When browsing the web it can get hard. I use Tab to select links, but there are often dozens of links on a webpage. I can use Chrome's text search (Ctrl-F) to home in on a piece of text in no time; But I can't figure out how to use it to click on a link.

For example, let's say there's a link on a webpage with the text "Swedish Furniture". I can easily find it by typing `Ctrl-F s w e d`, and then Chrome marks the link as found, but is there any way to follow the link after it's found without tabbing through all the links on the page?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To follow a link after it's found in search, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Chrome Search Cheat Sheet**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the search box.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> moves through all highlighted results.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> reverse move through all highlighted results.
4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> closes search box, turns off all highlights, selects the focused text/link
5. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to follow a link after highlights are off.

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Mac.

No extensions required.

Comment: It's just an incredible amount of extra typing, especially compared to Firefox.

Answer (score 51):

Another method is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (after highlighting in search).

Comment: Even better than that the accepted answer! (with less details about Chrome Search shortcuts, though) I'm glad I can upvote both answers and don't have to choose which one to accept.

Comment: Any way to ctrl + enter + something-else and have the link open in a new tab?

Comment: 1. Ctrl + F and search for link 2. Esc - will close search and leave link highlighted 3. Ctrl + Enter

Answer (score 5):

I have used **vimium**.
By installing its extension in chrome, you will be able to click any links on the page with shortcut **f**
For more information, you can refer to https://vimium.github.io/

Comment: You should include all relevant information in your answer.

Comment: I don't get your point. What do you mean all relevant information?  I just suggest to install one extension of Chrome. Once you install the vimium, you will know how to use it.

Comment: Its possible I was replying to the wrong answer, when I submitted that comment, we expect more out of extension recomendations other then "here use this ... instead ".  Question was answered 5 years ago, so new answers after all this time, are held to a higher standard.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple, easy to use chrome extension that solves this exact problem:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grep-click-type-button-te/ciokdkmjfdaidmcjmdmpjedgdflbfhng?hl=en-US&gl=CA

It's basically a control-f enhancement that lets you search for text of clickable elements on the page, cycle through results, and click on things.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use an extension to solve your problem? Try [Keyboard Navigation](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/abcekjakjehkpheoaadhkjfcdodpjbgk?hl=en); it should do what you want without any problems.

Comment: A bit slow, but seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried Keyboard Navigation but it's pretty bad.

Eventually, I found a plugin that works for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. It's quite good. Its also scriptable-- you can add custom selectors to pages you access often.

#### gleeBox

http://thegleebox.com/manual.html

What works well for links (No plugin, on a Mac running Chrome):
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, highlight the text in the page, then hit <kbd>escape</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd>.