# Click on link from the keyboard on search

Tags: firefox, keyboard, links

Is there any way to click on a link using the keyboard in Firefox?

E.g. Say I search for some text on an article on Wikipedia, and after iterating through the hits, the cursor sits on a link of interest. Can I click on it without using the mouse?

There is something along these lines [for Chrome already](https://superuser.com/questions/170353/chrome-selecting-a-link-by-doing-search-on-its-text), and it would be great to have this functionality in Firefox.

Comment: Press the Enter key if the cursor is on the link!

Comment: Vimperator! steep-curve tho. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/